# Problem the install package flutter_map in the vscode and android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, package

I get the following error when adding a package flutter map I do not know where the problem comes from ???

**image log**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvqOJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're an Iranian flutter developer
Always remember that you should have a good vpn
You can try proton vpn/Windscribe
After turning your vpn on try:
flutter clean
flutter pub get

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the package in pubspec.yaml file and press on pub-get to download and configure the package with your project.

But first of all, if you don't have the google services at your country, you have to connect via VPN to be able to work.